# Overloading an operator to allow different order of parameters in C++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, operators

Let's say I'm writing a class to represent 3D vectors for a computer graphics application. I would like to be able to multiply vectors by scalars, as shown below:

```cpp
Vector3D vec(1, 2, 3);  // The paramaters of the constructor are the x, y and z values
Vector3D vec1 = vec * 2; // Case A: result should be (2, 4, 6)
Vector3D vec2 = 2 * vec; // Case B: result should be (2, 4, 6)
```

To make case A work, I could add the following function to my class:

```cpp
class Vector3D
{
public:
    // ...
    const Vector operator*(int scalar) const;
};
```

To make case B work, I would have to create a function outside of my class:

```cpp
const Vector operator*(int scalar, const Vector& vec);
```

Note that I could also make case A work by adding the following function outside of my class:

```cpp
const Vector operator*(const Vector& vec, int scalar);
```

My question is: what is the cleanest way to do this? I could add one function inside my class and one function outside of it, or I could add two functions outside of my class. I like the idea of adding two functions outside of the class because I could keep them next to each other, which I think is clearer since they essentially do the same thing, but does adding one of the functions inside the class have any benefits that I am not seeing?

Note that the return values of my functions are const so that users can't do this (as explained by Scott Meyers in his book Effective C++):

```cpp
Vector3D vecA(1, 2, 3);
Vector3D vecB(1, 2, 3);
Vector3D vecC(1, 2, 3);

vecA * vecB = vecC;
```

Comment: I believe the same book also says you should prefer non-member non-friend functions to member functions because it increases encapsulation or something.

Comment: Not really sure what question you are asking.  "...but does adding one of the functions inside the class have any benefits that I am not seeing?"  No.  For a different class, it could.  This case, no.

Comment: This is highly oppinion based and probably better for [Software Engineering SE](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since multiplying a vector by scalar is symmetric, in the sense that there's no clear "superior" or "subordinate" participant, I would use a pair of free-standing operator overloads:

```
const Vector operator*(int scalar, const Vector& vec);
const Vector operator*(const Vector& vec, int scalar);
```

When you have a choice between overloading a member function vs. overloading a freestanding function, the decision should be based on the participation of the object itself in the computation with respect to function's parameters.

When the object plays central role, while parameters play peripheral role, keep the function with the object by making it a member. When the object and function parameters play similar roles, i.e. when there is a degree of symmetry between participants, a freestanding function is more appropriate.

Answer (score 4):

The usual approach is to provide `operator *=(int)` as a member function and then write free functions `operator*(Vector3D, int)` and `operator*(int, Vector3D)` that call it.

Answer (score 1):

The `operator*` here is symmetric (as in `a * b` and `b * a` should be equivalent operations) so you should prefer having both of the functions outside of the class.

Aside from what you mentioned - that having them near each other makes it cleaner - *it also allows implicit conversions for either operand*. On the other hand, if you had the `operator*` for Case A be a member function then implicit conversions of the left hand operand to `Vector3D` type is not allowed, but conversions of the right hand operand to `Vector3D` type is allowed (unless you mark the constructors `explicit`, but that's besides the point).

By using twin nonmember functions we have true symmetry, in that both operands have the same ability to be converted to the `Vector3D` type.

By the way, the [C++ Core Guidelines written by Bjarne Stroustrup and Herb Sutter](http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Ro-symmetric) also suggest doing this.